# ALU in Minecraft, what can be achieved with this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Recently articles popped up of how someone created a working ALU in Minecraft.  For example, [this article on ALU in Minecraft](http://www.osnews.com/story/23845/Working_16bit_ALU_Implemented_in_Minecraft). He is quoted in some articles saying he is going to take it a step further and create a real-working computer in Minecraft (a computer in a computer).

If he achieves this, what could be a possible application of a real-working computer inside a video game?  Or is this more of a video game simulation of how computers work?

Comment: This is about Computer Engineering, not gaming.  It can (supposedly) perform all things an ALU can do in a real computer, so this might be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit

Comment: The only way this could be conisdered on topic I think would to be to ask specifically about gameplay usages of an ALU. Which I think would be little to none.

Comment: @Alex, showing off _is_ the point of Minecraft. :)

Comment: I thought it was surviving the horrible night.

Comment: @Alex It's about surviving the horrible night so you can resume your showing off.

Comment: Well played salesman...

Comment: This has been achieved many times and combined with RAM and ROM and a command block based GPU to create some basic computers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no application, any more so than any software virtual machine or emulator has any application. In short, anything that can be done with an ALU built in Minecraft can be done more easily and efficiently without playing Minecraft.

It may however, be less fun. Certainly, there is educational value in something like this, with the right teacher. But that's orthogonal to any sort of practical use.

Answer (score 9):

The first thing that comes to mind is a pinpad.

You owe the Internet Oracle a combination lock system for an iron door.

Comment: Building an entire ALU just so that you can password your door is an amazing idea.

Comment: The first to do this can safely be said to have Won Minecraft.

Comment: I'll just dig under the door then... ;)

Comment: @jblaske good point, by the way did I talk with you about that lava pool installed squarely below my home? It's great for warming up ;D

Comment: Now *thats* a security system! At least once notch gets damage working on multiplayer.

Comment: @jblaske real diehards make their protected rooms out of bedrock.